# cassandra 過去の時点のテーブルを取得したい

Tags: database

cassandraというno sql DBを勉強しています。
cassandraで過去の時間を指定してその時点での内容のテーブルを取得したいと思っています。
cassandraでそのようなことは可能でしょうか？
cassandraでできない場合にはたとえば他のDBならできる等の代替案はありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cassandra にそのような機能があるとは、聞いたことがないです。また、 cassandra は eventual consistency の世界で生きているデータベースで、それにおいて歴データを取り扱うことに、意義を見出すのは少し難しそうです。

cassandra を使うのであれば、ロジカルな cassandra データの pk たちの末尾に、inserted_time のようなpk を追記して、insert 時にはこの inserted_time に現在時刻を入れておいて、後はロジックで頑張る、というのが解になりそうです。

ある特定時点のデータの状態を取得できるデータベースは、名称としては Temporal Database と呼ばれるそうです。調べてみると、いくつかこの機能を実装するデータベースがあるようで、具体的に一つあげると

- [mariadb の system versioned table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/)

などが使えそうです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
タイムスタンプというのがあったのであるいは過去データを再現できるのではと思いましたがだめですか。
mariadb の system versioned table 調べてみます。